# healthgraphic api ssl certificate verify fail

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, python-requests, anaconda, urllib

When I try to access the [healthgraphic](https://developer.healthgraphic.com/doc/) API using the latest Anaconda installation on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) I always get the following error

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed (_ssl.c:645)>
```

I'm not a programmer. My background = Doctor of Medicine/wanting to use Python to explore this healthgraphic api to help patients help themselves but I'm stuck on this first step despite spending hours trawling the net. So, in desperation I'm asking for help from support@healthgraphic.com & stackexchange

```
import urllib
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

datalink = 'https://api.healthgraphic.com/v1/symptoms/cough'

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'token': '7ho6immu3cw04sc4w8448c4okwgckkg'
}

try:
    url = datalink
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    saveFile = open('withHeaders.txt','w')
    saveFile.write(str(respData))
    saveFile.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

There is  a problem with verification of ssl certificates which I cannot solve (see below) & I would like you to help me to sort it out if you don't mind...

setting verify=False does not work & is insecure

installing/reintalling certifi does not work

updating requests does not work

export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt does not work

conda config --set ssl_verify /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt does not work

Does this help?

```
[1] % python -c "import requests; print(requests.certs.where())"
/home/*******/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```

If you can be of assistance I would be most grateful. From previous experience of posting questions I would like to apologize, in advance, for causing irritation.

Rgds,

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Healthgraphic reconfigured their servers & also pointed out that I was attempting to use the Get Symptoms method in the example but only the Get Condition Symptoms is available for free accounts: https://developer.healthgraphic.com/doc/reference/#condsx. That was a gotcha!

Anyway, I can connect with urllib2, urllib, or urllib3 & requests - I prefer the latter. This code works...

```
import urllib3
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
http = urllib3.PoolManager(
datalink = 'https://api.healthgraphic.com/v1/conditions/acute_sinusitis/symptoms?page=1&per_page=10'
    )

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'token': 'xxxx_your_token_here_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

try:
    url = datalink
    r = requests.get(datalink, headers=headers)
    print(r.json())

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```